# i want to show the sequence ftom 16 to 31 decimal number but its not showing :\ could anyone help me out here

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void bi(int a);
    int main()
    {
      // here is the issue how do start a loop, where i want the answer from 16 to 31 numbers
        int a=0;
       cout<<"Baum-Sweet Sequence From 16 to 31 \n";
       for(int j=a;j>16 && j<31;j++)
       {
           cout<<j; 
        }
       bi(a);
    system("Pause");
    }
    // Rest is working properly 
    void bi(int a)
    {
        int myArr[15],i=0,f=0,n=0;
        for (int h = 0 ; h <= a; h++)
        {
            int num = h;
            for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
            {
               myArr[i] = num%2;
               num = num/2;
            }
            for (int t = 0 ; t < 4 ; t++)
            {
                if (myArr[t]%2==0)
                    f++;
            }

            if (f%2==0)

                cout << " = " << 1;
            else
                cout << " = " << 0;
            cout <<endl;
        }
    }
```

i want to show the sequence from 16 to 31 decimal number but its not showing :\ could anyone help me out here

Comment: what is your code supposed to do? And what do you suppose the result of `int j=a;j>16 && j<31;j++` would be when `j==0` as it would be when you assign `a` to it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the for loop.

The for loop has three parts separated by a semicolon.

```
for (INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT) 
{
    // Source code for the for-loop's body
}
```

- The first part initializes the variable (e.g. "int j = 16;" means that through the variable j you begin counting by 16);
- The second part checks a condition and it quits the loop when false (e.g. j <=31 means that it quits the loop when j will have value 31);
- The third one is performed once each time the loop ends and then repeats (e.g. j++ means that at each iteration of the loop j will be incremented by 1).

Each iteration will execute the code in the body of the for loop.

Considering that you want to call the bi function for each value from 16 to 31 your for loop body should include bi(j). Your main should be modified like the code below:

```
int main()
{
     cout<<"Baum-Sweet Sequence From 16 to 31 \n";
     for(int j=16;j<=31;j++)
     {
         cout<<j;
         bi(j);
     }
     system("Pause");

     return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set j to 0, but then make a condition for the loop that it will only execute if j (which is set to a), is *bigger* than 16.

Your first thing to do is to make the loop conditions this:

```
for (int j = 16; j <= 32; j++)
```